# Any shortcuts for linear algebra?

Tags: objective-c, linear-algebra

Say for example I have 3 text boxes where the user will enter data into any 2 and then the third will be calculated.

The formula is `z=2x+c`.

The 3 text boxes are linked to `z`, `x` and `c`.

Do I need to write a statement along the lines of?

```
if c is blank then c=z-2x
if z is blank then z=2x+c
if x is blank then (z-c)/2
```

While this is fine with one equation, it may become tedious as my equations get more complex or I have a system of equations.

Are there any shortcuts or methods solving linear algebra in objective c?

Thanks

Comment: This is barely hard at all.. Why do you need "shortcuts"?

Comment: If I have a system of equations, say maybe 5, with atleast 4 variables in each, i'd have to write all the re-arranged variations of the equation. I can do it, I know it's not difficult, I thought i'd just ask to see if this can be done in an easier way.

Comment: where u need to put this equation ?? i mean ?? on component ??

Comment: Hi, I would be using the equations in a method that will be called when clicking a button. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Seems like an interesting problem, did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: No unfortunately I had to use if functions and then write the equation for every permutation.

Comment: Are you asking if there are library functions in objective-c to solve linear algebraic problems or if there is a linear algebraic way to represent this problem?